# How to add one day to a date which is given as 'month-day'?

Tags: php

I have a date which is:

```
$firstDay = "'" . date('m-d', easter_date(date('Y'))) . "'";
```

Output of `$firstDay` is: `'04-16'`. Now I need to create a second variable and add 1 day to the `$firstDay` variable. How should I do that? I red that I can do with `$date->modify()`, I'm trying like so:

```
$secondDay = $firstEasterDay->modify('+1 day');
```

But this doesn't work and I got an error.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Without a given year there's no clear answer for the end of February! In a leap year there's one more day in February than in other years. How does that factor into this task?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$date = "04-15-2013";
$date = strtotime($date);
$date = strtotime("+1 day", $date);
echo date('m-d-Y', $date);?>
```

Try This